# Mosaico mailing - link button showing coding

Tags: mosaico

[image]Hi would appreciate some advice - I sent out a newsletter using Mosaico and have received a message from one of the recipients saying that when the hover over a Link button they can see all the coding - example attached. Is there anything I can do to change this? Thanks Helen

Comment: the 'code' you are showing is the SendGrid link to the page. I don't think this is entirely a civicrm issue. it is normal that when you hover over a link that it shows you what the path is. the 'code' is being added by SendGrid

Answer (score 1):

The "Code" is just the url - it has a heap of alpha numeric characters because you have click tracking in Send Grid turned on. How Send Grid (and CiviCRM) itself tracks who clicks on a link is it has a link which is unique for each link for each email sent - when you click on that link Send Grid records the click against their list of who got sent that link - checks where the link should go and redirects the user through.

If you don't use click tracking in Sendgrid - and want people to be able to see the link in their email you can try turning click tracking off in your Sendgrid Dashboard. You might also have to do the same in CiviCRM if you have link tracking on there too.

Comment: Thank you that's really helpful!